# C/C++ Compiler that allows int width selection

Tags: c++, c, int, compiler-options

Does anyone know of a modern native Windows C or C++ compiler that allows you to select between 16-bit and 32-bit type int?  I encountered a cross-compiler back in the 80s that had this feature but I need a native compiler.  As part of teaching my students about portability and standards compliance I would like to be able to automatically check their code for overflow if they are multiplying, adding, etc. two type int quantities and the result would be greater than a 16-bit int could represent.  Thanks.

Comment: It is standard in the C++ language now. C++11 and forth see the types: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/integer `int32_t`, `int64_t`, etc.

Comment: `typedef` and tell your students to use the typedef'ed datatype?

Comment: If you do the `typedef` thing, just be aware that it's not strictly the same as using native 16-bit `int`. Using types `int16_t a, b;`, `a + b` might overflow on 16-bit system, but will never overflow on 32-bit system due to *usual arithmetric conversions*.

Comment: user 694733 has a good point, but the "`int16_t` is not a real `int`" problem pops up in more places. The constant `32768` won't be an `int16_t`, nor will the expression `1<<15`.

Comment: There's a meta-level question here: If you can't find a compiler where this matters, should you bother teaching it? It might be easier to use `long` for your course, because that does vary on real compilers (64 on GCC/x64, 32 on MSVC)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the integer types defined in C++11 and forth: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/integer : `int8_t`, `int16_t`, `int32_t`, `int64_t`

These should be supported by almost any modern C++ compiler: [GCC you can use MinGW on Windows](http://www.mingw.org/), [MSVC](https://www.visualstudio.com/), [Intel](https://software.intel.com/en-us/c-compilers), [Clang](http://clang.llvm.org/), even [Borland/Codegear/Embarcardero](https://www.embarcadero.com/products/cbuilder) as they are now part of the standard.

The fixed width integral types has been part of the C language since C99, but was finally added to C++ in C++11 see: [N1988](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2006/n1988.pdf)

Comment: I chose this as the best answer simply because some of suggestions in the previous postings would not work in my situation due to arithmetic type conversions.  I also have no control over the values that will be used in these variables.

Answer (score 1):

C++ compilers do support shorts. If this is for teaching, can't you just tell you students to use shorts rather than ints?

And if the purpose is just to tell them about overflows, why can't inputs be provided to the programs using ints that would cause overflows? inputs like 2 billion + 2 billion OR 2 billion x 6?

Back when this was a problem, people also used to define there own constants like INT16 and map them to underlying data type; like INT16 == short on C++.

Finally if you have problem with short, C++ does offer a 16 bit integer type as a standard data type since C++11.

If you do absolutely need an int to be 16 bit, you may find it in compilers such as Digital Mars that allow you to target Win 16 APIs, OR older versions of Visual Studio.

Comment: If this is for embedded programming, it is often very useful to know the exact width of the integer type used, and more importantly you want this to be portable across compilers and platforms. `__int16` is a vendor specific extension to the language, and not a native part of the language.

Comment: Absolutely. That is why most portable programs that I saw used things such as #defines of the form of INT16, and during porting used to change the #defines to whatever the equivalent was on the underlying system.

Comment: would it then not make sense to alter the part of your answer stating "Finally if you have problem with short, C++ does offer __int16" since C++ does in fact not offer `__int16` (although it does offer `int16_t`) but the compiler might offer it.

Comment: Makes sense. What would also make sense is altering your question where you stated your motive was to teach students about overflow and you sort of imply that ints have some inherent problems in teaching overflow.

Comment: Hi Amit, I am not the one asking the question. But I am the one presenting the answer. :)

Comment: ahh! my bad. If the problem is with portability, to the extent that someone if contemplating going to 16 bit, then best to stay with 'common' data types likely to be available with most compilers. Better that, then to hunt a compiler that supports all (later day) standard mandated data type

Comment: "Older versions of Visual Studio" is an understatement. VS2008 is old. VS6.0 is ancient. VS1.52 is 16 bits.